# Hampered read latency of all column families in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

I was trying to read the data from 100 partitions of one of the column family of Cassandra from Spark and it has 150-200 MB partition size. So, when I try to run this SparkJob on this column family read latency of rest of the column families also hamper. What could be the possible reasons for such behavior and solution for the same?

Comment: How many nodes do you have? If you have different column families but they live in the same nodes I think it's natural that reading from one may impact the performance of reading from the other.

Comment: i have 3 nodes in my cluster

Comment: Probably you can't do much besides [lowering read consistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html#dmlConfigConsistency__dml-config-read-consistency) or adding more nodes.

Comment: You might want to consider adding caching layer like Redis (see spark-redis)